# Does not work correctly in browsers jquery sorting (Opera, Chrome)

Tags: jquery, sorting

Not working properly sorting the list (class = "ytube_date") in other browsers (Opera, Chrome, IE). Works correctly only in firefox v22.0.
Tell me how to do the sorting by date video? My code is in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TsZeg/165/). Some values ​​`class = "ytube_date"` - empty

jquery:

```
function sortDescending(a, b) {
    var date1 = $(a).find(".ytube_date").text();
    date1 = date1.split('-');
    var date2 = $(b).find(".ytube_date").text();
    date2 = date2.split('-');
    return date1 < date2;
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#all_elements .element').sort(sortDescending).appendTo('#all_elements');
});
```

Html:

```
<div id="all_elements">

            <div class="element">
            <div class="ytube_form">
            <div class="ytube_form_new">
                <div class="ytube_pod_form">
                        <div class="ytube_date">2013-06-26</div>
                        <div class="ytube_time">0:16</div>
                        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/7n9rcgFMqxM?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1" rel="shadowbox[utube];height=542;width=1000;title=Промо 2 HD: Американская история ужасов (American Horror Story)(2011)(3 сезона)" title="Смотреть Промо 2 HD" ><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/7n9rcgFMqxM/1.jpg" border="0" width="126" height="95" alt="Player"/></a>
                </div>
                <div class="ytube_link">Промо 2 HD</div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>


                <div class="element">
            <div class="ytube_form">
            <div class="ytube_form_new">
                <div class="ytube_pod_form">
                        <div class="ytube_date">2013-06-28</div>
                        <div class="ytube_time">0:49</div>
                    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/cAYX3P4lZSE?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1" rel="shadowbox[utube];height=542;width=1000;title=Трейлер (rus): Американская история ужасов (American Horror Story)(2011)(3 сезона)" title="Смотреть Трейлер (rus)" ><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/cAYX3P4lZSE/1.jpg" border="0" width="126" height="95" alt="Player"/></a>
                </div>
                <div class="ytube_link">Трейлер (rus)</div> 
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="element">
            <div class="ytube_form_red">
            <div class="ytube_form_red_new">
                <div class="ytube_pod_form_red">
                        <div class="ytube_date">2013-06-28</div>
                        <div class="ytube_time">1:59</div>
                    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/zHZOoX57yS8?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1" rel="shadowbox[utube];height=542;width=1000;title=Трейлер 2 (RedBand): Американская история ужасов (American Horror Story)(2011)(3 сезона)" title="Смотреть Трейлер 2 (RedBand)" ><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/zHZOoX57yS8/1.jpg" border="0" width="126" height="95" alt="Player"/></a>
                </div>
                <div class="ytube_link_red">Трейлер 2 (18+)</div>   
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>


        <div class="element">
        <div class="ytube_form">
                <div class="ytube_form_new">
                    <div class="ytube_pod_form">
                        <div class="ytube_date">2013-06-27</div>
                        <div class="ytube_time">0:16</div>
                <a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/TFJXJy8ugBo?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1" rel="shadowbox[utube];height=542;width=1000;title=Тизер 6 (2 сезон): Американская история ужасов (American Horror Story)(2011)(3 сезона)" title="Смотреть Тизер 6 (2 сезон)" ><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/TFJXJy8ugBo/1.jpg" border="0" width="126" height="95" alt="Player"/></a>
                    </div>
            <div class="ytube_link">Тизер 6 (2 сезон)</div> 
                </div>
        </div>
        </div>


        <div class="element">
        <div class="ytube_form">
                <div >
                    <div class="ytube_pod_form">
                        <div class="ytube_date">2013-06-19</div>
                        <div class="ytube_time">2:04</div>
                <a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/63TLDsnYYlU?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1" rel="shadowbox[utube];height=542;width=1000;title=Фан-трейлер: Американская история ужасов (American Horror Story)(2011)(3 сезона)" title="Смотреть Фан-трейлер" ><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/63TLDsnYYlU/1.jpg" border="0" width="126" height="95" alt="Player"/></a>
                    </div>
            <div class="ytube_link">Фан-трейлер</div>   
                </div>
        </div>
        </div>


        <div class="element">
        <div class="ytube_form">
                <div class="ytube_form_new">
                    <div class="ytube_pod_form">
                        <div class="ytube_date">2013-06-27</div>
                        <div class="ytube_time"></div>
                <a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/97WHuuKqgrQ?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1" rel="shadowbox[utube];height=542;width=1000;title=O' Death: Американская история ужасов (American Horror Story)(2011)(3 сезона)" title="Смотреть O' Death" ><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/97WHuuKqgrQ/1.jpg" border="0" width="126" height="95" alt="Player"/></a>
                    </div>
            <div class="ytube_link">O' Death</div>  
                </div>
        </div>
        </div>


        <div class="element">
        <div class="ytube_form">
                <div >
                    <div class="ytube_pod_form">
                        <div class="ytube_date"></div>
                        <div class="ytube_time"></div>
                <a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/UvUHnS2uwI0?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1" rel="shadowbox[utube];height=542;width=1000;title=Moira O'Hara: Американская история ужасов (American Horror Story)(2011)(3 сезона)" title="Смотреть Moira O'Hara" ><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/UvUHnS2uwI0/1.jpg" border="0" width="126" height="95" alt="Player"/></a>
                    </div>
            <div class="ytube_link">Moira O'Hara</div>  
                </div>
        </div>
        </div>



        <div class="element">
        <div class="ytube_form">
                <div class="ytube_form_new">
                    <div class="ytube_pod_form">
                        <div class="ytube_date">2013-06-23</div>
                        <div class="ytube_time"></div>
                <a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Tpr5bgZ6YiE?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1" rel="shadowbox[utube];height=542;width=1000;title=Тизер 1 (2 сезон): Американская история ужасов (American Horror Story)(2011)(3 сезона)" title="Смотреть Тизер 1 (2 сезон)" ><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/Tpr5bgZ6YiE/1.jpg" border="0" width="126" height="95" alt="Player"/></a>
                    </div>
            <div class="ytube_link">Тизер 1 (2 сезон)</div> 
                </div>
        </div>
        </div>


        <div class="element">
        <div class="ytube_form">
                <div >
                    <div class="ytube_pod_form">
                        <div class="ytube_date"></div>
                        <div class="ytube_time"></div>
                <a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/7JDB_q83IZg?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1" rel="shadowbox[utube];height=542;width=1000;title=Тизер 3 (2 сезон): Американская история ужасов (American Horror Story)(2011)(3 сезона)" title="Смотреть Тизер 3 (2 сезон)" ><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/7JDB_q83IZg/1.jpg" border="0" width="126" height="95" alt="Player"/></a>
                    </div>
            <div class="ytube_link">Тизер 3 (2 сезон)</div> 
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>





        <div class="element">
        <div class="ytube_form">
                <div >
                    <div class="ytube_pod_form">
                        <div class="ytube_date"></div>
                        <div class="ytube_time"></div>
                <a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/42w-Wye7gXc?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1" rel="shadowbox[utube];height=542;width=1000;title=Тизер 5 (2 сезон): Американская история ужасов (American Horror Story)(2011)(3 сезона)" title="Смотреть Тизер 5 (2 сезон)" ><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/42w-Wye7gXc/1.jpg" border="0" width="126" height="95" alt="Player"/></a>
                    </div>
            <div class="ytube_link">Тизер 5 (2 сезон)</div> 
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>


        <div class="element">
        <div class="ytube_form">
        <div class="ytube_form_new">
                    <div class="ytube_pod_form">
                        <div class="ytube_date">2013-06-23</div>
                        <div class="ytube_time"></div>
                        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/d24adem9WLM?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1" rel="shadowbox[utube];height=542;width=1000;title=Саундтрек: Американская история ужасов (American Horror Story)(2011)(3 сезона)" title="Смотреть Саундтрек" ><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/d24adem9WLM/1.jpg" border="0" width="126" height="95" alt="Player"/></a>
                    </div>
            <div class="ytube_link">Саундтрек</div> 
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

</div>`
```

Comment: You should add your code here as well unless it's extremely long, having to go to another site just to see your code is annoying. JSFiddle etc should be use to let others test your code.

Comment: I added this code in question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

your return value in the custom sort is wrong

it needs to return -1 if the first one is less then the second, 1 if the first greater than the second and 0 if equal to each other, and you can take out the splits unless you need to compare them differently .

```
function sortDescending(a, b) {
    var date1 = $(a).find(".ytube_date").text();
    var date2 = $(b).find(".ytube_date").text();
    return (date1 < date2) ? -1 : (date1 > date2) ? 1 : 0;
};
```

Comment: Awesome, this was a missing pieces that was resulting in some values being out of order but mostly right

Answer (score 0):

change this code:

```
$('#all_elements .element').sort(sortDescending).appendTo('#all_elements');
```

to

```
$('#all_elements .element').sortDescending().appendTo('#all_elements');
```