# jQuery sort table row by the value of one td

Tags: jquery

How would you sort this table by the `pts` class that I have:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>rank</th>
        <th>team</th>
        <th>pts</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1.</td>
        <td>Chelsea</td>
        <td class="pts">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2.</td>
        <td>Arsenal</td>
        <td class="pts">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3.</td>
        <td>Man U</td>
        <td class="pts">2</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button>SORT</button>
```

code:
http://jsfiddle.net/dxL8b2k0/

Comment: `id`s should be unique in a document. You are duplicating `id="pts"`.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I have changed it to class, any idea how?

Comment: Don't forget to use `<thead>` and `<tbody>` elements. Looks like you've got a good answer below for the sorting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For having a valid table, you should wrap the first `tr` with a `thead` element and other `tr`s with a `tbody` element. For sorting the `tr`s you can use the `sort` method:

```
$('tbody > tr').sort(function (a, b) {
    return +$('td.pts', b).text() > +$('td.pts', a).text();
}).appendTo('tbody');
```

For updating the rank cells you can use the `text` method:

```
$('tbody > tr').sort(function (a, b) {
    return +$('td.pts', b).text() > +$('td.pts', a).text();
}).appendTo('tbody').find('td:first').text(function(index) {
    return ++index + '.';
});
```

Comment: The support on `localeCompare` isn't that great, maybe just `return $('td.pts', a).text() - $('td.pts', b).text()`?

Comment: After your edit, it will not work since you have string. It will evaluate the first character, so `'12' < '3' === true`. You need to parse it like `+$('td.pts', b).text() > +$('td.pts', a).text();`

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Yes, that's completely true. Thanks for mentioning it!

Comment: How would you make the rank number to stay sticky by order?

Comment: lets say the table is dynamic and you often have to sort, arent you supposed to detach and sort and then attach back?

Comment: @PirateApp That process happens behind the scenes by the browser's DOM engine.

Comment: That doesn't work for me on chrome browser. See here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379916/does-not-work-correctly-in-browsers-jquery-sorting-opera-chrome

Answer (score 5):

See this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avhmznx1/3/) for a working version:

```
$('#btnGo').on('click', function () {
    // get rows as array and detach them from the table
    var rows = $('#tbl tr:not(:first)').detach();

    // sort rows by the number in the td with class "pts"
    rows.sort(function (row1, row2) {
        return parseInt($(row1).find('td.pts').text()) - parseInt($(row2).find('td.pts').text());
    });

    // add each row back to the table in the sorted order (and update the rank)
    var rank = 1;
    rows.each(function () {
        $(this).find('td:first').text(rank + '.');
        rank++;
        $(this).appendTo('#tbl');
    });
});
```